# removed navigated to messages in chrome console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to remove the navigated to messages from the chrome console?

I like to preserve logs to quickly see history but the navigated to messages add a lot of unneeded clutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings -> Preferences -> Console-> Uncheck the 'Preserve log upon navigation'.

[image: Screenshot of steps]

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can find is filtering messages by script.

[image: filtering console messages in chrome devtools by script]

And I don't see any methods for programmatically removing individual messages in the [Console API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference?hl=en).

Comment: Everything else seems to be coming from somewhere but Navigated to is not from anything so I don't think you can filter it that way